# A prime’s square dividing a sum of a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

For what $p$ primes does there exist two positive integers $(a,b)$, such that
$$\dfrac{1-a^p}{1-a}=bp^2?$$

This is from a junior olympiad from Britian but I can’t solve it. Please help!

Comment: Is this an ongoing competition, or one that has been completed?  I ask because we have a strict rule against answering questions from ongoing contests, and it's best to be sure.

Comment: Thats from the past, year 2011

Answer (score 3):

Consider instead $\frac{(a+1)^p-1}{a}-bp^2=a^{p-1}+\binom{p}{p-1}a^{p-2}+\cdots+\binom{p}{1}-bp^2$. Now apply Eisenstein's Criterion with prime $p=p$. $p$ doesn't divide $1$ infront of of $a^{p-1}$. Each binomial coefficient is divisible by $p$ (in particular since $p$ is prime). Finally $p-bp^2$ is divisible by $p$, but not by $p^2$. So the polynomial is irreducible over the rationals in $a$. There are no such $(a,b)$ for $p>2$.

Edit: Mike rightfully points out that the degree one case is special. In this case if $p=2$, then the polynomial becomes $a+2-4b=0$, which has solutions $a=2(2b-1)$, e.g. $a=2,b=1$, or in the original notation $(a=3,b=1
)$.

Comment: The exception is $p=2$, with solution $a=3,b=1$ (in your variation, $a=2,b=1$). Irreducible does not imply no roots in the special case where the polynomial has degree one.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Whoops, of course you're right. Thanks!!

Comment: It might be helpful to say that because the polynomial is irreducible, it has no rational zeros, and in particular there is no such a.